# Is resetting of JVM same as termination of JVM in BlueJ?

Tags: java, bluej

In BlueJ whenever I run a class I find I small button at the bottom of the project window labelled "reset Java Virtual Machine". Shown below:

[image: Reset Java Virtual Machine Button]

Comment: No. If you restart the JVM it will be terminated and the started again by reloading all source files. By terminating it will not do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Resetting" the JVM actually terminates the current JVM, and then starts a new JVM to take its place. Note that this option is available whether or not you are currently running any code. It always removes all objects from the object bench, resets static variable values (due to the classes being re-loaded), and closes any windows opened by user code in the user JVM.

(I am one of the BlueJ developers).

Comment: Ah! Yes, the static variables are reset! Didn't notice that earlier.